# remote oracle database connection

Tags: oracle

I am working on a project using oracle.The remote host pc ip address is 10.100.59.30 where my database exists.I want to connect the database from my computer(ip:10.100.59.150). How should I do it?Oracle listener is working fine.But Showing network adapter is not connecting.I checked the firewall.It is off.All is fine but database connection is not building up.I have tried every possible solution.Am I missing some silly things?I have tried with `sqlplus username/password@hostA:1521 /XE` in cmd.but not working.And I do not have oracle installed in my pc.

Comment: Your oracle db is in linux box or windows server? As well what is the output when you doing telnet from your client machine... telnet 10.100.59.30 1521 ??

Comment: windows ......Connecting To 10.100.59.30...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1521
: Connect failed...there is another issue host pc is not getting internet connection...although host pc is connected by wifi

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [tnsnames.ora](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF263)? Or here is [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:45033135081903) answer how to connect to oracle without one.

Comment: Then the port should be defined there, shouldn't it? Something like this `(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = your.host)(PORT = 1521))
    )`

Comment: And `sqlplus username/password@hostA /XE` doesn't work?

Comment: yes..i wrote this command on cmd but it is showing 'sqlplus 'is not recognized as external and internal command

Comment: Well, to use sqlplus you need to add its location to the environment variable PATH, or you need to specify full path when you call it. Mine is somewhere like `c:\app\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\`, it depends on where you installed oracle client.